# 14.04 Hangs on Shutdown

Tags: shutdown

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on this HP laptop and it seems to be hanging on shutdown.  Removed "quiet" and "splash" from the boot line so I could get a verbose shutdown.  When it gets to "Will now halt", it just sits there.

I can't seem to find a log that contains these shutdown messages or I would include it.  I've checked /var/log/syslog and /var/log/kern.log and they don't contain any shutdown information.  I've tried doing an "updatedb" and doing a search for the words "Will now halt" but nothing comes up.

The "fail" in the image below appears to be coming from "Killing all remaining processes".

[image: Shutdown log]

Comment: I'm not sure the wireless drivers would affect the shutdown, either. Particularly as I have exactly the same problem, but with an RaLink wireless card, not Broadcom! Did you make any other changes that could have affected the shutdown?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was resolved after I got the correct drivers installed for my Broadcom wireless card.  I'm not exactly sure why wireless drivers would affect the computer's ability to shut down, but after I corrected a problem with the wireless drivers the computer started shutting down normally.